# SQL insert from multiple tables and a list of integers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need a SQL statement for the following for SQL Azure.

I have 2 tables with data :

- `Tenants` (relevant column: Id)
- `Users` (relevant column: Id)

A user has no direct link with the tenant table.

I need to fill up a third table `OptInMail` (relavant columns: `TenantId`, `UserId`, `OptInType`) with for each user, for each tenant for each value of the `OptInTypeList` a record.

```
OptInTypeList = 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 14
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into OptInMail (TenantId, UserId, OptInType) 
    select 
        t.id, u.id, 1 
    from 
        Tenants as t, Users as u;

...<put same statements with values 2,3,10,11 as far as there are not so many to write>...

insert into OptInMail (TenantId, UserId, OptInType) 
    select 
        t.id, u.id, 14 
from 
    Tenants as t , Users as u ;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yes, they are deprecated. Sadly CROSS JOIN is just as bad in performance no matter how you write it.  I still fall back to the old school method if I write one... it's usually demo code, i still haven't pushed a cross join into production.

Comment: i assume this question was about how to populate the table once. i did a quick solution by first and that's it. i do agree with both of you. but in a real world sometimes there is a place for quickest solution instead of the perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into OptInMail (TenantId, UserId, OptInType)
select distinct t.id, u.id, o.id
from Tenants t cross join Users u 
cross join ( values (1), (3), (10), (11), (14) ) o (id)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 insert into OptInMail (TenantId, UserId, OptInType)
 select distinct t.id, u.id, o.id
 from Tenants t cross join Users u cross join OptInTypeList o
```

if you list are not a table:

```
 insert into OptInMail (TenantId, UserId, OptInType)
 select distinct t.id, u.id, o.id
 from Tenants t cross join Users u cross join 
 (
 select 1 id union all
 select 2 id  union all
 select 3 id  union all
 select 10 id  union all
 select 11 id  union all
select 14 id 
 ) o
```